2 types of wifi issues
Port, board, and/or hardware
ESP32 with micropython
MicroPython version
esp32-20220618-v1.19.1.bin
Reproduction
Issue No.1:On startup
Issue No.2:On startup / while running
Expected behaviour
Connected to the wifi smoothly and kept that.
Observed behavior
Issue No.1: "Wifi internal error" occurs. After the power is off and on, sometimes it works but mostly not. Once it gets recovered, it keeps working without any error which looks strange to me. Just adding print(anything) may have solved...
Issue No.2:I'm using 30+ ESP32 with micropython. Most of them connect wifi smoothly and keep it. But some 1 or 2 of them suddenly start struggling to connect wifi when starting up(cannot connect even after the reboot, unplug power, and plug) or lose connection when it's working. But after a while, it works completely normal. The boards that have this issue are random.
(1)This is the code to connect wifi.
"""Wifi"""
def connect_wifi(ssid, passkey, timeout=5):
global speed_filtered, bias, speed_raw
wifi= network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wifi.active(False)
time.sleep(1)
wifi.active(True)
wifi.connect(ssid, passkey)
start = time.time()
start_count = time.time()
while not wifi.isconnected():
print('*')
time.sleep(1)
if time.time()-start > timeout:
    wifi.disconnect()
    time.sleep(1)
    wifi.connect(ssid, passkey)
    start = time.time()

if wifi.isconnected():
    print('Connected')
    print(time.time() - start_count)
    return wifi

(2) this is the code to check the wifi status. If it's not connected, it tries to reconnect.
if wifi.isconnected():
    if wifi_strength > 80:
        wifi_strength_category = 4
    elif wifi_strength > 60:
        wifi_strength_category = 3
    elif wifi_strength > 40:
        wifi_strength_category = 2
    else:
        wifi_strength_category = 1
else:
    wifi = connect_wifi(SSID_NAME, SSID_PASS)

